# How to get .onHover(...) events for custom Shapes

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Say you have a `Circle`. How can you change its color when you hover inside the circle?

I tried

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hovered = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(hovered ? .purple : .blue)
            .onHover { self.hovered = $0 }
    }
}
```

But this causes `hovered` to be `true` even when the mouse is outside of the circle (but still inside its bounding box).

I noticed that the `.onTapGesture(...)` uses the hit testing of the actual shape and not the hit testing of its bounding box.

So how can we have similar hit testing behavior as the tap gesture but for hovering?

Comment: Does onTapGesture use hit testing on the shape ?  It doesn't seem to work for me when I have a rotated rectangle - it still seems to be using the frames rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the precision you need. The hove in SwiftUI currently just monitor the MouseEnter and MouseExit events, so the working region for a view is the frame which is a `Rectangle`.

You may build a backgroundView in ZStack which can compose those  `Rectangle` with a customized algorithm. In circle shape, it should be like a matrix with different some small rectangles. One oversimplified example could be like the following.

```
  ZStack{
                            VStack{
                            HStack{
                                Rectangle().frame( width:100, height: 100).offset(x: -50, y: 0)
                                Rectangle().frame( width:100, height: 100).offset(x: 50, y: 0)
                                }}.onHover{print($0)}
                            Rectangle().foregroundColor(hovered ? .purple : .blue).clipShape(Circle())
                        }
```

Comment: I want to have the same precision as the `.onTapGesture` on Shapes.

Comment: Then it becomes a geometry question, filling a circle with minimal number of rectangles

Comment: The question is for custom shapes. I gave an example with `Circle` for easy reproduction purposes but I really need it to work with any [Shape](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape)

Comment: It’s an adaptive integral question then.

Comment: A simple way is to fill the area with lineViews which have 1px. Height